# Change screen lock from password to pin

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I have a Samsung Note 4 and I set the screen lock to use a password.  Now I want to change it from password to another option, but it is not possible.  Please advise me on how to remove the screen lock password.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not possible"?  What have you tried and what error are you encountering?  It should be a straightforward option in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You enter ***settings>security>screen security>*** and select how you want to unlock. You then will have to provide the password, maybe twice. Once the password is entered, choose another lock method.

If you forgot your password, then that is another question.