# Android 11 missing change lock screen PIN

Tags: lock-screens, android-11

In a new Android phone, OS version 11, I can't find the change lock screen PIN.

In this phone, privacy and security are separate (i.e., some related questions direct users to "Privacy and Security" -- [Change screen lock from password to pin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88146/change-screen-lock-from-password-to-pin)).

The Settings > Security shows the lock screen PIN item, but when opened it does not list an item to change it. And the options of Screen lock, are limited to 1) lock screen timeout and 2) power button activation.

As the screenshot below shows, I have not set up a Device admin app.

[image: Screenshot of Android version 11 Security screen]

**When I click the cog next to "Screen lock," I see the content illustrated by the screenshot below:**

[image: Screenshot of Android's 11 Settings > Security > Lock screen PIN submenu item]

How can I change my lock screen PIN or set a pattern or password?

Comment: Have you tried [tapping the "Screen lock/PIN" text (left of the cog wheel icon)](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079129) instead? If it's empty, could you also take a screenshot of it?

Comment: The second Screenshot you see in this post, is the content of cog @AndrewT. is referring to

Comment: I meant to press the text on the left, not the cog itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press the word "Screen lock PIN" instead of the cogwheel icon. Enter your pin if prompted. Then select PIN again to enter a new PIN